# Best way to read data from contract using eosjs or Cleos

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, eosjs

How you read the data from your contracts, just by using actions? Or there is another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's RPC API: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference.
To read the data stored on the blockchain by contracts, one can use [`get_table_rows`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows).

Also, you can browse contract tables in some block explorers, like https://bloks.io.

In case you are asking for something else, please clarify the question.

Comment: By using the get table, it seems best as you said. Could you share how I could get particular row and not the whole table and filter it in the js later?

Comment: @Kristian There's example tabs on the developers.eos.io site, using cURL, Node, Ruby, JavaScript, and Python. Then just fill in the fields below, and you get the code in the window. Finally, change `http://127.0.0.1:8888` to `https://api.eosnewyork.io` or some other API endpoint.

Comment: Didn't know about those examples. It worked nice, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like that works for now:
cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io get table contractName contractName tableName --index 1 --key-type i64 -L 1234123423451235  -U 1234123423451235

this way I am searching for the given id - 1234123423451235

Thanks!